# Would Restore the Peace affect a hexproof creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Would restore the peace affect creatures with hexproof?

I have [Archetype of Endurance](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Archetype%20of%20Endurance) (all creatures you control have hexproof, your opponent cannot have hexproof). I attack and then my opponent plays [Restore the Peace](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Restore%20the%20Peace), would this affect my creatures since they have hexproof?

Answer (score 5):

**Yes.**

Hexproof means that the creature with Hexproof cannot be the **target** of spells or abilities an opponent controls. Restore the Peace does not target creatures, it's a global effect, so Hexproof does not offer any protection in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As Hackworth said,

[Restore the Peace](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Restore%20the%20Peace) will effect creatures with hexproof. Hexproof creatures are protected from spells that "target" them, but aren't protected from spells that effect the entire battlefield (even those with conditionals).
A card like Restore the Peace effects **each** creature that dealt damage, and would therefore effect hexproof creatures because it does not target them.